# make bokeh plot fill the entire screen

Tags: bokeh

I am using bokeh to plot a google map and I can set the size manually as follows:

```
self.plot = gmap(self.api_key, self.map_options, title=title)
self.plot.width = 800
self.plot.height = 300
show(self.plot)
```

This works fine but is there a way to ask it to fill the browser with the map i.e. some sort of a full screen like mode?

Answer (score 1):

Ok, I figured t out. Posting it as an answer in case it helps someone. Use [`gridplot`](https://docs.bokeh.org/en/latest/docs/reference/layouts.html)

So something like:

```
layout = gridplot([[self.plot]], sizing_mode='stretch_both')
```